# Python POST requests - how to extract html of request destination

Tags: python, python-requests

Scraping data of mortgage from official mortgage registry. The problem is that I can't extract the html of particular document. Everything happens on POST behalf - I have all of the data required to precise the POST request, but still when i'm printing the request.url it shows me the welcome screen page. It should retrieve html from particular document. All data like number of mortgage or current page are listed in dev tools > netowrk > Form Data, so I bet it must be possible. I'm quite new in web python so I will apprecaite any help.

My code:

```
import requests

data = {
'kodWydzialu':'PT1R', 
'nrKw':'00037314', 
'cyfraK':'9',
}

r = requests.post('https://przegladarka-ekw.ms.gov.pl/eukw_prz/KsiegiWieczyste/wyszukiwanieKW', data=data)

print(r.url), print(r.content)
```

Comment: is this information that should be get ? https://ibb.co/tzRhKCC

Comment: Unfortunately the number of mortgage is included in POST, not GET. But if u mean that I want to get that scrap then answer is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the welcome screen because you aren't sending all the requests required to view the next page.

Go to Chrome > Network tabs, and you will see that when you click the submit/search button, a bunch of other `GET` requests are being sent to different URLs after that first `POST` request.

[image]

You need to replicate that in your script. Depending upon the website it can be tough to get the response, so you should consider using [Selenium](https://selenium.dev/)

That said, it's not impossible to do this with `requests`:

```py
session = requests.Session()
```

You need to send the `POST` request, and all other `GET` requests that follow in the same session.

```py
data = {
'kodWydzialu':'PT1R', 
'nrKw':'00037314', 
'cyfraK':'9',
}

session.post(URL, headers=headers, params=data)

# Start sending the GET requests
session.get(URL_1, headers=headers)
session.get(URL_2, headers=headers)
```